# How to add attribute to exist IXMLDOMNode in c++?

Tags: c++, xml

Can you please give me an example of how to add an attribute to exist `IXMLDOMNode` in C++?

Answer (score 2):

I read the name and the value of the attribute and then do the follow:

```
CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> pElement;
 hr = pNodeSrc->QueryInterface(IID_IXMLDOMElement,(void**)&pElement);
 hr = pElement->setAttribute(name,val);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but reading the reference ([here's the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd875276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) I think you can use `IXMLDOMDocument::createAttribute` method.

```
HRESULT createAttribute(
    BSTR bstrName,
    IXMLDOMAttribute** ppAttribute
);
```